# use a variable as array id

Tags: php, variables

I have this code:

```
$speciesid2 = 1927;

$array3 = array('id'=>'$speciesid2');
$type3 = 'species';
$r3 = $client->fetch($type3,$array3);
```

I need the 1927 of the variable speciesid2 inside of the `'id'=>'$speciesid2'`.

I tried it like this but it doesn´t work.

Comment: Unquote it (`'$speciesid2'`) and it should work.

Comment: Single quotes build a literal string so you get the dollar sign and all. Either unquote it or switch to double-quotes so that variables are properly interpolated.

Comment: Worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$array3 = array('id'=>$speciesid2);
```